# How to open the keyboard programatically when using showSoftInputOnFocus=false on text input in react native (android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In an **Android** react-native application, I want when I focus a text input to not open the keyboard automatically (Later, I will open it using it's ref)

I have found that `showSoftInputOnFocus={false}` will not open the keyboard when focusing, but afterward, I am not able to open it programmatically using `ref.current.focus()`

How can I open the keyboard programatically when using `showSoftInputOnFocus=false` ?

Comment: The only way is to use a state key as value for `showSoftInputOnFocus`  and then when you want to open Keyboard first update the state key responsible for `showSoftInputOnFocus`  to `true`  and then you can focus the input and the keyboard will show up.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the same behavior and I could tackle it by using states.